# Sale undefined en el DOM al hacer una petición AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

He creado una función en *JavaScript* y no sé por qué me sale `undefined`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function actualizaDatosIzquierda() {
        var fecha = new Date();
        var temperatura_actual = getTemperaturaActual();
        $("#temperatura").text("\u00a0"+temperatura_actual+"ºC");
        $("#humedad").text("\u00a0"+getHumedadActual()+"%");
        $("#estado").text(getEstado());
        $("#maximas").text("\u00a0"+getTemperaturaMaxima()+"ºC \u00a0\u00a0"+getHumedadMaxima()+"%");
        $("#minimas").text("\u00a0"+getTemperaturaMinima()+"ºC \u00a0\u00a0"+getHumedadMinima()+"%");
        $("#ultima-actualizacion").text(fecha.getHours()+":"+fecha.getMinutes());
    }
    actualizaDatosIzquierda();
    setInterval(actualizaDatosIzquierda, 60000);
});

function getTemperaturaActual(){
    $.ajax("getLast.php").done(function(msg) {
        var res = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(res["temperatura"].substring(0, 4));
        return res["temperatura"].substring(0, 4);
    })
}
```

Lo curioso es que en la consola sí me sale correctamente el número, pero en el elemento *HTML* sale `undefined`.

El string `temperatura` es algo así: `"23.4"`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sale `undefined` porque estas devolviendo un valor desde una operación asíncrona. Tienes que entender el `callback` que proporcionas al método `done`(es una operación diferida) se ejecutará cuando la petición haya resuelto. Y hasta ese momento `getTemperaturaActual` ya ha sido ejecutado y no ha devuelto ningún valor.

Una solución es setear el valor de la temperatura cuando acaba la operación asíncrona es decir, cuando se ejecuta `done`.

```
function getTemperaturaActual(){
    $.ajax("getLast.php").done(function(msg) {
        var res = JSON.parse(msg);
        console.log(res["temperatura"].substring(0, 4));
        var temperatura_actual = res["temperatura"].substring(0, 4);
        $("#temperatura").text("\u00a0"+temperatura_actual+"ºC");
    })
}
```

Otra es usar las promesas de javascript que se introdujeron en la versión ES6.

Comment: ha funcionado, llevaba dos días bloqueado ahí, muchas gracias.